# given that $f(1)=2, f(2)=8$ and $f(a+b)-f(a)=kab-2b^2$, find $f^\prime (x)$

Tags: calculus

given that $f(1)=2, f(2)=8$ and $f(a+b)-f(a)=kab-2b^2$, find $f^\prime (x)$
for any arbitrary x.
I am clueless on this one

Comment: $f'(x)=\frac{f(x+b)-f(x)}{b}|_{b=0}=\frac{kxb-2b^2}{b}|_{b=0}=(kx-2b)|_{b=0}=kx$. The second equation is by putting $a=x$ in the given formula. So, you only need to find $k$. Put $a=b=1$ to get that $8-2=f(2)-f(1)=k\cdot1\cdot1-2\cdot 1^2$.

Comment: This is an easy problem, you will have to declare or let a and b in such a way that you get f(x), which means (1+x-1 = x) so take a = 1 and b = x-1 or vice versa. Then, solve the equations to get f(x), once you got dat you will be able to take the 1st order derivative and get f '(x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(2)- f(1)= f(1+ 1)- f(1)= k(1)(1)- 2(1^2)$ so 8- 2= 6= k- 2 and k= 8.

That is, $f(a+ b)- f(a)= 8ab- 2b^2$.

Then $f'(x)= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+ h)- f(x)}{h}=$$ \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{8hx- 2h^2}{h}= \lim_{h\to 0} 8x- 2h= 8x$.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the equation, the information that $f(1) = 2$ and $f(2) = 8$ allows you to determine the value of $k$ (think of explicit values you can set $a$ and $b$ to that allows you to exploit this).

With $k = k_0$ determined, as OscarRascal mentions, from the equation you are given you then have
$$
f(a + b) - f(a) = k_0ab - 2b^2
$$
or perhaps in more familar notation,
$$
f(x + h) - f(x) = k_0xh - 2h^2.
$$
Divide both sides by $h$ and let $h\to0$ to then find the general formula for $f'(x)$.

Comment: That is, if such a function exists... see my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the given equation holds for all $a, b\in \Bbb R$, there is no such function $f$.

Putting $a = 1$ and $b = x - 1$ in the equation, we get $$f(x) - f(1) = k(x - 1) - 2(x - 1)^2.$$ Putting $x = 2$, we see that $k = 8$. Hence $$f(x) = 2 + 8(x - 1) - 2(x - 1)^2 = -2x^2 + 12x - 8.$$

But then $f(a + b) - f(a) = -4ab + 12b - 2b^2$, so this cannot hold for all $a, b$.

Comment: Why not? The function $f(a) := -2a^2 + 12a + C$ satisfies this for all $C\in\mathbb{R}$ and every $a, b$..

Comment: I also don't get why that cannot be. You will have $-2b^2+12b-4ab=8ab-2b^2$  which holds when a=1, after all, everything follows from this assumption which you started with right?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see that such a function cannot exist is to set $a=0$. Then we have

$f(b) - f(0) = -2b^2 \\ \Rightarrow f(0) = f(b)+2b^2$

With $b=1$ this gives $f(0)=4$, but with $b=2$ this gives $f(0)=16$.

However, if $f(a+b)-f(a) = kab + 2b^2$ then $f(x) = 2x^2$ and $k=4$.

Comment: How does $f(x) = 2x^2$ imply that $k = 4$?

Comment: @DanBurrows Because $2(a+b)^2 - 2a^2 = 4ab + 2b^2$.

Comment: I see yes. Checked by seeing that yes, $"f'(x)" = 8x$, which then implies $f(x) = 4x^2 + c$, but no $c$ can satisfy the conditions $f(1) = 2$ and $f(2) = 8$. It must be that those conditions impose values that cannot be obtained by that type of quadratic. Nice spot anyway.

Comment: I don't think that you should get a unique solution. The way I see it, your solution will depend on how you pick your u, plus the question says you should find the derivative for any arbitrary x not for all x.